# Parameter setting issue in ssrs report from winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services

From my win form application i unable to pass int and date time as parameters,when i try to pass , the program giving error.
so here i converted all my parameters as string and pass,but the report is accepting ,int,date time,date time as there parameters from the respective stored procedure.so it generating error report.

```
                  string ID = "1 ";
                 string DateStart= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString();
                 string DateEnd= DateTime.Today.ToString();
rptParameters[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("@ID", ID);
 rptParameters[1] = new ReportParameter("@DateStart", DateStart)    
 rptParameters[2] = new ReportParameter("@DateEnd", DateEnd);
```

Is there any solution to pass other than string parameters from winform to SSRS reports.

Comment: Why does your ID string have a space at the end? And why haven't you told us what the error you were getting is? And why are you using the fully-qualified name of `ReportParameter` for the first parameter?

Comment: Error is this "The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter.ReportParameter(string, string)' has some invalid arguments" and what u mean by fully Qualified Name . here my sql parameter is@BUID i just edited the parameters and give.

Comment: here this error comes when i try to pass some int value instead of string values

Comment: Please edit this information into the question rather than adding it as comments. By "fully qualified name" I mean you're using "Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter" once, and then just "ReportParameter" afterwards. Also edit in the error you're *now* getting. Basically, read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [by the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportparameter.reportparameter%28v=vs.80%29) (and the error message), the parameter value should be a string.
Use `ID.ToString()`, `DateStart.ToString()`  and `DateEnd.ToString()` as your parameters.

```
rptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("@ID", ID.ToString());
rptParameters[1] = new ReportParameter("@DateStart", DateStart.ToString());    
rptParameters[2] = new ReportParameter("@DateEnd", DateEnd.ToString());
```